# Serial Port in C# receiving event

Tags: c#

How to define a serial port in C# such that

`Form1` Contains initialisation and port open statements

```
_Serial_Interface.PortName = COM16;

_Serial_Interface.BaudRate = 115200;

_Serial_Interface.Parity = Parity.None;

_Serial_Interface.DataBits = 8;

_Serial_Interface.StopBits = StopBits.One;

_Serial_Interface.Open();
```

(where as)

`Form2` contains `DataReceived` Event.

```
public void _Serial_Interface_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{ 

}
```

Comment: Serial ports cannot be shared.  One consequence of that is that you can always declare your variable *static*.  Also make it public and now it is dead-easy, in your Form2 constructor you simply add Form1.Serial_Interface += this.Serial_Interface_DataReceived;  Do think through what should happen when the user closes that Form2 instance.

Comment: Hi Hans, How can I update a textbox string defined inside "static serial datareceived" method?

Comment: Your event handler does not have to be static.  You don't want it to be static.